# ubuntu in virtual box becomes slow and laggy after maximizing or viewing any app full screen

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I have just recently started using Ubuntu linux version 18.04.1 LTS in virtual box. Now everyting is fine in usual case. But when I maximize or make any Ubuntu apps fullscreen, Ubuntu becomes very slow and laggy and I have to restart to resolve the issue.

I have already install **`guest additions`** and enabled **`3d acceleration`** and maximized the video memory to **128 mb** . I have also run this command : `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` and it shows 3d acceleration enabled.
I have install `linux-headers`, `dkms`, `build-essential`, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody have an idea about it? It will be a great help.

**Note:** I am not talking about making whole VM instance fullscreen. I am able to do that just fine. Its the apps inside Ubuntu that I want to work fullscreen but it starts to lag as soon as I hit the maximize button in top-right.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Apparently the problem is caused by the 3d acceleration. Disable it should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have this exact same problem as well. My 3D acceleration is already disabled, so I do not think it is the cause of the problem. Currently, my video memory is at 128mb as well.

Comment: Disabling 3D acceleration won't speed up. It just makes it stream lined like what you see in minimized screen speed is the exact same when you go full screen.